# Installing MRPT on Fedora

Tags: robotics, mobile-robot-toolkit

Can anyone provide a detailed procedure for installing MRPT on Fedora 33 Scientific (one of the Fedora Labs which has a KDE interface)? The MRPT installation instructions for Ubuntu mentions something about cmake/cmake-gui. Checking the man pages, F33Sci has no such thing. It must be possible to accomplish this somehow, because Fedora Robotics Lab includes MRPT. I've already tried "$sudo dnf install mrpt", resulting in "Error: Unable to find a match: mrpt". However, "$dnf search mrpt" results in a bunch of items from mrpt-base... to mrpt-stereo-camera-calibration.

Answer (score 0):

The version of MRPT that ships with Fedora is really outdated, so you do well in building from sources.

`cmake-gui` is not 100% required, it is only mentioned in the instructions to make things easier to those preferring GUIs, but you should be able to compile using the console commands [here](https://docs.mrpt.org/reference/latest/compiling.html#using-the-console) (that is, the standard workflow with cmake).

Next, the CMake configuration process will warn you about missing libraries. Most are optional, but at least make sure of installing eigen3, opencv and wxwidgets. Those should be installed with the standard commands used in Fedora...

Comment: I tried this procedure, without success. eigen3, opencv and wxwidgets are all present. Carrying out the console cmake procedure results in " --Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!" message. (How can I include attachments of the Output and Error log files?)

Comment: I think it's better at this point to open an issue ticket [at the project repo](https://github.com/mrpt/mrpt/issues), and attach the error log there.